# python, tkinter specificy buttons

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

player1 = []
player2 = []

class MakeSq:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.sqs()
        self.again()

    def sqs(self):
        self.square_frame = (self.master)
        self.square_frame.grid()
        self.quan = 17 # make this game universal, you can add more squares
        for s in range(1, self.quan * self.quan + 1, 1):
            self.b = s
            self.b = Button(self.master, width=3, command=lambda x=s: self.mark(x), font=('times', 16))
            self.b['command'] = lambda x=s, which=self.b: self.mark(x, which)
            self.place_it(s) # place square on the right place
            self.b.grid(row=self.r, column=self.c)

    def place_it(self, s):
        self.r = 0
        while s > self.quan:
            s -= self.quan
            self.r += 1
        self.c = s % (self.quan + 1)

    def mark(self,x , which):
        if len(player1) == len(player2):
            player1.append(x)
        else:
            player2.append(x)
        if len(player1) == len(player2):
            p = 'O'
            p_c = 'dark blue'
        else:
            p = 'X'
            p_c = 'orange'
        which.config(text=p, fg=p_c, command='')
        self.check_win(player1)
        self.check_win(player2)


    def check_win(self, player):
        for p in player: # iba p + 4 moze byt delitelne 17, kluc k vyrieseniu problemu s riadkami
            if p + 1 in player and p + 2 in player and p + 3 in player and p + 4 in player:
                print('win')

            elif p + 17 in player and p + 34 in player and p + 51 in player and p + 68 in player:
                print('win')

            elif p + 18 in player and p + 36 in player and p + 54 in player and p + 72 in player:
                print('win')

            elif p + 16 in player and p + 32 in player and p + 48 in player and p + 64 in player:
                print('win')


    def again(self):
        self.again_bt = Button(self.master, text='New game', command=self.restart)
        self.again_bt.grid(column=200)

    def restart(self):
        self.sqs()
        player1.clear()
        player2.clear()

    def show_result(self):
        pass


root = Tk()
plan = MakeSq(root)
root.mainloop()
```

This code create 289 buttons. How can I specificy each button ? For example if I click button number 50, function `self.mark()` will be active for this button, but how can I active function `self.mark()` for specificy button without click on the button.

**EDIT:**
I edited my code, you can run it now. I want create Tic-Tac-Toe game. This code should create game for two players. If you click button, text of button will change. Purpose of function `self.mark()` is change text of button and check if someone win. It works, but **I want add bot / computer against me.** So after I do my move (click button), bot will do his move. There will be function what find the best move, and do this move (it should change the text of specific button without click this button). **How I can change text of specific button without click this button ?**

Comment: How do I run this code?

Comment: Will each of them call the same function?

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: @Marty alright, I'm sure you're doing a great job, but it's not an easy task like this -- you need to create a "clever" bot who will play a brain game against a human, this is called AI (Artificial Intelligence). Do you have knowledge in this field?

Answer (score 1):

You're using .grid() method to place/group your widgets (mostly buttons) so you can use it to identify at which row/column a button is.

```
    def mark(self,x , which):
        ...

        # Lets say human is using 'X' marks (player1)
        # So the bot is left with 'O'.
        if p == 'X': self.BotMakeMove(which) # Human made a move so it's Bots turn

    def BotMakeMove(self, button):
        row     = int(button.grid_info()['row'])
        column  = int(button.grid_info()['column'])

        print ("Human pressed button at index: {} {}".format(row, column))

        # Do some calculation
        # 
        # 


        # You're done and lets say you wont to press the button right of humans
        row     = row           # ...
        column  = column + 1

        self.press(row, column)


    def press(self, row, column):
        for children in self.master.children.values():                                                                 
            if children.grid_info()['row'] == str(row) and children.grid_info()['column'] == str(column) and children['command']:
                player2.append(0)           # You should pass that 'x' value here.
                children.config(text='O', fg='dark blue', command='')
                return True

        print ("Button at index {} {} doesnt exist or is being used.".format(row, column))
```